# GitHub in other languages

Tags: github, localization, translation

I came across this post on the GitHub blog: [GitHub in your language](https://github.com/blog/679-github-in-your-language), but I can't seem to find the option to use the GitHub website in another language. The links in the blog post that append a GET parameter to the URL seem to do nothing apart from that, and the post refers to links in the footer which I can't find.

Does anyone know how I can get a localized version of GitHub? It seems strange that such a widely used application isn't localized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/web.php), this is what the footer used to look like when they had the translation options circa late 2010:

> [image: github footer from 2010]

A redesign or two since then has removed the footer, and that the URL parameters have no effect, it's looking like that feature has been quietly deprecated from the GitHub web interface.

Also, you can't load SSL pages via Google Translate or Bing Translate, so using those to filter the page in a non-English language will unfortunately not work.

Unless there is another service that will translate SSL delivered pages (all of github.com is served over SSL), you can't live render a local translation of github.com to read.